# Error occurring when sharesdk.framework is added in project

Tags: iphone, gmail, cocos2d-x, share

I am a new cocos2d-x gaming developer for the iPhone. I want to share a screenshot of my game on Facebook and Gmail. I am using the Sharesdk.framework but when I drag and drop the Sharedsk folder and framework in my project, multiple erros generate in the project so I'm unable to use it. Is there any solution for resolving these errors? (I'm getting errors such as "jni.h file not found" and "sharesdkcoreservice.h" not found.)